# (Softlayer api) How to get connection information for evault webcc and authenticate with the web?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm tring to develop a function that provides a webcc link(example:  https://ev-webcc01.service.networklayer.com/Login/login.aspx) for my users.
How can I get the webcc link url for the evault products through softlayer api? 
Softlyser control web (control.softlayer.com) is providing a single sign on function with the webcc, how does it can be developed?

Comment: Hi, Your URL can't open .please check it again ,thanks

Comment: You must be connected to softlayer vpn to open this url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is not possible to get the webcc link via API. But below is a Rest request to get 'webccAccount' (The account username and password for the EVault webCC interface).

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getEvaultNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask(SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6)[agentStatuses,backupJobDetails,webccAccount]

Method: GET
```

It may help you in some way.

**Reference:**

[SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6)